# Walmart Seller API POST not working

Tags: php, curl, walmart-api

I am attempting to POST to the Walmart Seller API using CURL i PHP to acknowledge orders.

https://developer.walmartapis.com/#acknowledging-purchase-orders

for some reason it will not accept my method or it returns "Bad Request".

anyone with experience in this?

```
$apiheaders = array(
'WM_SVC.NAME: Walmart Marketplace',
'WM_QOS.CORRELATION_ID: 1466113345',
'WM_SEC.TIMESTAMP:1466113345447',
'WM_SEC.AUTH_SIGNATURE: XXXXXXXXXXX'
'WM_CONSUMER.ID: XXXXXXXXXXX',
'Content-Type: application/xml',
'Accept: application/xml',
 );

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $apiheaders);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$return_api_host);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out?

Comment: If you still need help do let me know i have created a model in PHP for Walmart API in Zend.

Comment: i was able to figure this out thanks. i was actually using the wrong method in my signature generator

Comment: can you provide the solution as I am facing the same issue

Comment: is it possible you provide solution i also face same problem and guide for how to pass xml file for feed .

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was from my header signature. Not shown here. Don't forget to create the signature for the correct type of transmission. Eg post,get etc. I had it set as get on my previous calls and did not make it a variable as it should have been.

Feel free to post your example so we can see.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$consumer_id='xxxxxxxxxx';
$private_key='xxxxxxxxxx';
$timestamp='xxxxxxxx';
$correlation_id='xxxxxxxxxxx';
$channel_id='xxxxxxxxxx';

$endPoint = "v3/orders/".$purchaseOrderId."/acknowledge";
$requestUrl = "https://marketplace.walmartapis.com/$endPoint";
$requestMethod = 'POST';
$signature = new Signature($consumer_id, $private_key, $requestUrl,$requestMethod);
$actual_signature = $signature->getSignature($timestamp);

$headers = [];
$headers[] = "WM_SVC.NAME: Walmart Marketplace";
$headers[] = "WM_QOS.CORRELATION_ID: ".$correlation_id;
$headers[] = "WM_SEC.TIMESTAMP: ".$timestamp;
$headers[] = "WM_SEC.AUTH_SIGNATURE: ".$actual_signature;
$headers[] = "WM_CONSUMER.ID: " .$consumer_id;
$headers[] = "Content-Type: multipart/form-data";
$headers[] = "Accept: application/xml";
$headers[] = "WM_CONSUMER.CHANNEL.TYPE: ".$channel_id;
$headers[] = "HOST: marketplace.walmartapis.com";


$body['data'] = array();

$ch = curl_init ();
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $requestUrl );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1 );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
$server_output = curl_exec ( $ch );
?>
```